# setBackground on List items with TransitionDrawable

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-cardview

In my `RecyclerView`, I have a list of items(`using custom adapter`). every row has some text inside a `cardview`, for example like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2" />


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I decided to animate items background color (`cardview background`) with `TransitionDrawable`. So I had to get specific item by its position. So the only thing I could think of was `getter`&`setter` through my Model Class like:

```
public TransitionDrawable getTrans() {
    return trans;
}
public void setTrans(TransitionDrawable trans) {
    this.trans = trans;
}
TransitionDrawable trans;
```

Then use it like:

```
holder.card.setBackground(product.getTrans());
```

And then:

```
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)};
TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
product.setTrans(trans);
trans.startTransition(5000);
```

But this is giving me `StackOverflowError` for generating `getter&setter` for TransitionDrawable in my Model class.

So the question is how can I achieve something like this?

**Update**

Adapter:

```
public class LocalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Activity activity;
private List<ProductLocal> dataList;

public interface PlayPauseClick {
    void playPauseOnClick(int position);
}
private PlayPauseClick callback;
public void setPlayPauseClickListener(PlayPauseClick listener) {
    this.callback = listener;
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public LocalAdapter(Activity activity, List<ProductLocal> dataList) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.dataList = dataList ;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
             inflate(R.layout.local_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


    ProductLocal m = dataList.get(position);


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
        holder.card.setBackground(m.getTrans());
    } else {
        holder.card.setBackgroundDrawable(m.getTrans());
    }


    holder.playPauseHive.setImageResource(m.getPlayPauseId());
    holder.playPauseHive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.playPauseOnClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    });

}

public ProductLocal getItemAtPosition(int position){
        return dataList.get(position);
}


public void setDurationPlayingColor(int position){
    ProductLocal product = getItemAtPosition(position);
    ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)};
    TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
    product.setTrans(trans);
    trans.startTransition(5000);
   }

 }
```

PlayPause Callback in `Fragment`:

```
        public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
        ProductLocal product = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        int selectedUrl = product.getRes();
        if (product.paused) {
            adapter.setDurationPlayingColor(position);
            //*****************************
            startMediaPlayer(selectedUrl);
            //*****************************
        } else {
            adapter.setDurationDefaultColor();
            stopMediaPlayer();
        }
}
```

*Many thanks in advance for any help.*

Comment: Can you post your adapter class?

Comment: @azizbekian Thanks for the reply, I've added into my question.

Comment: Who calls `setDurationPlayingColor()` and how often? Also post full stacktrace.

Comment: @azizbekian It gets called in my `Fragment` wich contains a list of `audio` with `play` button in every row. when play button gets clicked,(via `playPauseOnClick` callback)

Comment: @azizbekian I reached my limits for adding codes for `stackTrace`

Comment: May the [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) be with you.

Comment: @azizbekian https://pastebin.com/R7Fk49iB

Comment: @azizbekian I updated gson from 2.7 to 2.8.1 and the exeption is gone.everything works now. thanks by the way. you have been a great help to me this days